# Calculating an angle of a triangle with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

Sorry for the pretty dumb question. 
I'm slowly learning maths from scratch.

I would like to calculate the angle of triangle through javascript.

I calculate the lengths of the sides,

```
Ab = Math.abs(b.x - c.x);
Ac = Math.abs(b.y - c.y);

A = Math.sqrt((Ab*Ab) + (Ac*Ac));

Bb = Math.abs(a.x - c.x);
Bc = Math.abs(a.y - c.y);

B = Math.sqrt((Bb*Bb) + (Bc*Bc));

Cb = Math.abs(a.x - b.x);
Cc = Math.abs(a.y - b.y);

C = Math.sqrt((Cb*Cb) + (Cc*Cc));
```

And then I get to this point:

```
angleB = Math.cos(((C*C) + (A*A) - (B*B))/(2*C*A));
```

However, I get a completely wrong number. Why is this so?

Comment: Maybe you don't realize that most languages deal with radians, but you're expecting degrees. It'll be easy to tell if you post the number you get and the one you expect.

Comment: Triangles have *three* angles. Which are you trying to calculate?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? Which 'angle' are you looking for?

Comment: He's looking for angle B, which is the angle opposite side B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code uses `Math.cos` when it should use `Math.acos`.

Starting with the [law of cosines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), we derive the correct formula:

```
b*b = a*a + c*c - 2*a*c*cos(angleB)
b*b - a*a - c*c = - 2*a*c*cos(angleB)
2*a*c*cos(angleB) = a*a + c*c - b*b
cos(angleB) = (a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2*a*c)
angleB = acos((a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2*a*c))
```